# Selection of interaction terms for logistic regression

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, interaction

I'd like to use regularized logistic regression to classify elements (DNA sequences, i.e., character strings) into one of two categories based on the presence/absence (1/0) of many (k=50) features (DNA sequence motifs, i.e., substrings). I have approximately 20000 elements, which are split approximately 90:10 between my two classes.

I expect there to be significant interactions among some of these features (I mean non-additive effects between specific pairs of features), so I believe I want to include interaction terms in my model. Doing this exhaustively would mean examining a large number of interactions (50 choose 2=1225). To me, this seems bad--I don't think I have enough data to accurately fit a model with so many terms, and I would expect fitting such a model would be computationally challenging.

If I were working with a smaller number of features, would it be best to fit a model with all possible interactions, and then perform a post-hoc analysis of which terms significantly improve the model? For my current case, is it valid to pre-filter for specific interactions of interest (by identifying pairs of features that are enriched in (cooccur more often in) one class of elements vs. the other)? Thanks for your input.

Comment: What about kernel logistic regression with perhaps a polynomial kernel?

Comment: Roughly how many such elements/ observations do you have?

Comment: Edited post to clarify # of elements/split between classes.

Comment: What about using best subset-selection or shrinkage (i.e. ridge regression or lasso): http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127444/a-guide-to-regularization-strategies-in-regression